# Does tar help compression?

Tags: unix, compression, tar

I know `tar` doesn't compress but simply archives. However, does it help compression much for the compressor running on the back end, such as `gzip` or `lzma`?

Another way of wording it is if compressing individual files first then archiving would take significantly more space.

This basically comes from a logs that get rolled daily but archived and compressed at the end of the week. There are about 30-50 files up to tens of GB each. When you need to get those files for processing, uncompressing and untarring take a significant amount of time, especially because often you only want a few files from the tarball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring 30-50 files of 10Go won't significantly improve compression rate or speed. Files are so big compared to the number of files that you won't win much in dictionary size. Read https://superuser.com/questions/616785/how-does-dictionary-size-affect-compression for better understanding.

==> You'd better not make big tarball but zip them individually.